# Does prerender.io support cookies?

Tags: angularjs, prerender

I am trying to use a local installation of prerender.io to generate static snapshots of an Angular.js webapp.

The webapp's backend uses a session cookie that is being set on the first request and required on all subsequent ones - if it is not being sent, the requests fail (they are being rejected by the backend). This works fine when using the webapp in a normal browser.

In prerender.js all requests work except for those that call the backend - those fail, because apparently phantomjs does not send cookies.

Is it true that prerender.js does not support (or disables) cookies? If so: what can I do to enable them? Phantomjs supports cookies, as far as I know ...

Comment: I had a similar problem on an app that I worked on. The solution was to detect if the request came from prerender.io and use a special guest account for those cases instead of denying the requests.

Comment: @EtienneMaheu Okay, that would be a solution - albeit a pretty ugly one :( ... thanks for sharing anyway!

Comment: Well, technically, you should never expose private data (information protected by a security token) over search engines so this is not a problem that should arise. The only reason why we had this issue was because our backend always requires a login token, even for guest sessions. It just made sense to consider prerender as a special guest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cookies are turned off by default since most crawlers don't use cookies, but for the cases where your website doesn't work due to needing cookies, you can set the COOKIES_ENABLED environment variable to true or pass the option in when creating the prerender server in your code:

```
var server = prerender({
    cookiesEnabled: true
});
```